# Problem with filter control with versions >1.14.2

Tags: bootstrap-table

When using a newer version of bootstrap table than 1.14.2 my filter control does not work any more. I want to have a select field (which I have), but when choosing any value from the dropdown field nothing is filtered. It worked perfectly well for version 1.14.2.

I am filling my table from an php script. The values in the select field are there, just the filtering does not happen.

I am using the newest version of Joomla on my website

1.14.2 version which worked: https://12ndr.at/entry-ranking-men
1.15.3 version which does not work: https://12ndr.at/entry-ranking-men-old

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/extensions/accent-neutralise/bootstrap-table-accent-neutralise.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/extensions/fixed-columns/bootstrap-table-fixed-columns.js"></script>    

<div class="table-responsive table-sm small">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed" data-filter-control="true" data-search="true" data-search-accent-neutralise="true" data-search-align="left" data-sort-name="Position" data-sortable="true" data-toggle="table" data-url="https://12ndr.at/scripts/ranking.php?gender=m">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="4" data-halign="center">&nbsp;</th>
        <th colspan="3" data-halign="center">Entry Ranking</th>
        <th colspan="3" data-halign="center">World Ranking</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="Position" data-order="asc" data-sortable="true">Position</th>
        <th data-field="TeamName" data-sortable="true" data-width="500" data-width-unit="%">Team</th>
        <th data-field="Federation" data-filter-control="select" data-filter-control-placeholder="Country" data-sortable="true">&nbsp;</th>
        <th data-field="Flag" data-sortable="false">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="font-weight-bold" data-field="EntryPointsTeam" data-sortable="true">Points</th>
        <th data-field="EntryPointsPlayer1" data-sortable="true">Points #1</th>
        <th data-field="EntryPointsPlayer2" data-sortable="true">Points #2</th>
        <th class="font-weight-bold" data-field="RankingPointsTeam" data-sortable="true">Points</th>
        <th data-field="RankingPointsPlayer1" data-sortable="true">Points #1</th>
        <th data-field="RankingPointsPlayer2" data-sortable="true">Points #2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: its working fine for me

Comment: On my website or on yours?